# Wildcard folder match powershell

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

I have following Power Shell script I need to modify.

```
$filepath = "F:\feeds\Amazon\"
$temppath = $filepath+"temp.csv"
$files = ls -Path $filepath *.csv
foreach ($file in $files){
    gc $file.FullName |
    % { if($_.indexOf("|~|") -eq -1) {$_ -replace "`"((?:`"`"|.)*?)`"(?!`")", "|~|`$1|~|" -replace "`"`"", "`""} else {$_ -replace " ", " "}} |
    sc  $temppath
    ri $file.fullName
    rni -Path $temppath -NewName $file.fullName
}
```

This script loops through all .csv files in a defined folder and change the text qualifier. Now I need to change this a bit and I am stucked.

Basically my CSV files are spitted into multiple folders like. Amazon1, Amazon2, Amazon3 .. so on. Is there anything wild card match sort of things I can do here so that it looks into all folders whose name starting with Amazon?

I Don't want to loop through folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

... The `*` character? Try this:

```
$filepath = "F:\feeds\Amazon*"
$files = ls -Path $filepath *.csv -recurse
foreach ($file in $files){
   $temppath = $file.directoryName+"\temp.csv"
   gc $file.FullName |
   % { if($_.indexOf("|~|") -eq -1) {$_ -replace "`"((?:`"`"|.)*?)`"(?!`")", "|~|`$1|~|" -replace "`"`"", "`""} else {$_ -replace " ", " "}} |
   sc  $temppath
   ri $file.fullName
   rni -Path $temppath -NewName $file.fullName
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Yes withe `Get-child-Item` Cmdlet (dir) you can use wild card match on folders :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\Amazon?\" -include *.csv -Recurse
```

Comment: That's great. Just a note that with Question Mark(?) it didn't select Amazon10 and further folders. So had to go with *